# The proportion of binary digits of $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \Big\lfloor{\frac{k}{2}\sqrt{p}\Big\rfloor}\cdot2^{-k}$ equal to one, is $> 0.978$ if $p=143$.

Tags: number-theory, probability-theory, irrational-numbers, binary

Can you prove this? Is it true? If $p$ is an integer, is this proportion never equal to 50%? See my related question regarding this sum, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3484773/coincidences-in-sum-k-left-lfloor-frack2-sqrt-p-right-rfloor2-k-and). For $p=143$, I computed the binary digits in Excel using carry-over operations implemented in Excel formulas. The first few digits equal to zero take place at the following locations:

```
47, 95, 143, 191, 239, 287, 335, 383, 431, 479, 527, 574, 622, 670, 718, 766, 814, 862, 910, 958, 1006, 1054, 1102, 1149, 1197, 1245, 1293, 1341, 1389, 1437, 1485, 1533, 1581, 1629, 1677, 1724, 1772, 1820, 1868, 1916, 1964, 2012, 2060, 2108, 2156, 2204, 2252, 2299, 2347, 2395
```

The delta between two successive locations with a zero digit, is 48 most of the time, and sometimes 47. So, less than 1 out of 47 binary digits is equal to zero, though this is not a proof, just a statement based on observations. More precisely, the location delta is 47 (rather than 48) between a zero digit and the previous one, only at the following digit positions: $574+ k \cdot 575$, for $k=0, 1, 2$ and so on.

You can thus compute the exact proportion of binary digits equal to one. Can you compute that proportion? It must be - it seems - between $1-\frac{1}{47}$ and $1-\frac{1}{48}$, and much closer to $1-\frac{1}{48}$ than to $1-\frac{1}{47}$. I assumed here that we are only interested in the fractional part, and the first digit for the fractional part of the number in question, is assigned position 1.

***The exciting thing here is the discovery of a class of (presumably) irrational, non-normal numbers, that are rather natural. Usually such numbers are built artificially.*** Other similar numbers include the [rabbit number](https://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/some-fun-with-the-golden-ratio-time-series-and-number-theory), and numbers described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3341627/a-simple-irrational-number-with-the-same-first-11-667-755-digits-as-frac23) (or problem #11 in [this article](https://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/two-new-deep-conjectures-in-probabilistic-number-theory)).

**Other spectacular examples in the same family**

Besides $p=143 = 11 \times 13$, with first zero digit in position **47**, we have:

- $p = 17 \times 19$: the first binary digit equal to 0 is in position **71**; about 98.3% of the digits are equal to 1.
- $p = 29 \times 31$: the first binary digit equal to 0 is in position **119**; about 98.7% of the digits are equal to 1.
- $p = 41 \times 43$: the first binary digit equal to 0 is in position **167**; about 99.1% of the digits are equal to 1.
- $p = 59 \times 61$: the first binary digit equal to 0 is in position **239**; more than 99% of the digits are equal to 1.

Sounds like if $p$ is the product of twin primes, it leads to interesting results. Would be interesting to see if the sequence that includes the numbers $47, 71, 119, 167, 239, \cdots$ is well known.

**A case with known exact solution**

By *known*, I mean that the exact proportion of binary digits equal to 1 is a known, explicit algebraic number. Not a proof, but it is based on my experience dealing with this kind of stuff, and strong empirical evidence.

The case $p=2$ leads to very strong and simple patterns in the distribution of the binary digits. The proportion of digits equal to 1 is $\sqrt{2}/2$. An immediate consequence is that the number that has these digits, is irrational. Below are the first 2,000 or so digits.

```
11011011101101110110110111011011101101101110110111011011101101101110110111011011011101101110110111011011011101101110110110111011011101101101110110111011011101101101110110111011011011101101110110111011011011101101110110110111011011101101101110110111011011101101101110110111011011011101101110110111011011011101101110110110111011011101101110110110111011011101101101110110111011011011101101110110111011011011101101110110110111011011101101110110110111011011101101101110110111011011011101101110110111011011011101101110110110111011011101101110110110111011011101101101110110111011011101101101110110111011011011101101110110110111011011101101110110110111011011101101101110110111011011101101101110110111011011011101101110110110111011011101101110110110111011011101101101110110111011011101101101110110111011011011101101110110110111011011101101110110110111011011101101101110110111011011101101101110110111011011011101101110110111011011011101101110110110111011011101101101110110111011011101101101110110111011011011101101110110111011011011101101110110110111011011101101101110110111011011101101101110110111011011011101101110110111011011011101101110110110111011011101101110110110111011011101101101110110111011011011101101110110111011011011101101110110110111011011101101110110110111011011101101101110110111011011011101101110110111011011011101101110110110111011011101101110110110111011011101101101110110111011011011101101110110111011011011101101110110110111011011101101110110110111011011101101101110110111011011101101101110110111011011011101101110110110111011011101101110110110111011011101101101110110111011011101101101110110111011011011101101110110110111011011101101110110110111011011101101101110110111011011101101101110110111011011011101101110110111011011011101101110110110111011011101101101110110111011011101101101110110111011011011101101110110111011011011101101110110110111011011101101101110110111011011101101101110110111011011011101101110110111011011011101101110110110111011011101101110110110111011011101101101110110111011011011101101110110111011011011101101110110110111011011
```

The lag-1 autocorrelation in this sequence of binary digits seems to be equal to $1 - \sqrt{2} < 0$, a value that is way too small for the number in question to be normal in any base $b$ with $1< b \leq 2$. See chart in section 4.1.(b) in [this article](https://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/fascinating-new-results-in-the-theory-of-randomness) for details.

**Useful reference**

See second half of the following [Wolfram article](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DevilsStaircase.html) about the Devil's staircase.

Comment: What do you mean by "proportion" here? Is it natural density?

Comment: Yes, natural density, as in $0.10101010\cdots$ has 50% ones.

Comment: This would certainly be amazing if true...

Comment: What do you mean by 'carryover operations implemented in Excel formulas'? Also, given the answer to your other question and the note that $\sqrt{143}\approx 12-\frac1{24}$ (and in particular the fact that it has a lot of large-ish coefficients in its continued fraction, which is why the next-order approximation is also an excellent one), I would think you'd need to go much further before the fact that it's so near an integer finally gets washed out. I would suggest using a bignum package and computing roughly a million digits of this; that would give much more confidence.

Comment: I have a bignum package, haven't used it yet for this problem, and I'll share my Excel spreadsheet. The digit pattern is true for the first 200,000 digits, I can go easily to 10,000,000 digits. I noticed something similar (same kind of pattern) with the rabbit number: the proportion of binary digits equal to zero in the rabbit number, is $(3 - \sqrt{5}) / 2$ which of course proves that it is an irrational number. See https://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/some-fun-with-the-golden-ratio-time-series-and-number-theory. That said, all I wrote so far is just conjectures.

Comment: I uploaded my spreadsheet with the carry-over formulas. It's about 10MB, and goes to 212,026 digits, see here: http://datashaping.com/mathr-ST.xlsx. It's easy to extend it to 1,000,000 digits, and with some piece of code, to 100,000,000 digits. Note that the last 40 or so digits shows a random 50/50 proportion of 0 and 1, but that is because we are missing digits between position 212,027 and $\infty$, creating errors in the carry-over calculations. Go to 300,000 digits, it will erase these errors (they'll show up, always, in the last 40 or so positions before you stopped.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's look more generally at sums on the form
$$
S = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \lfloor ka\rfloor\cdot 2^{-k}
$$
where $a>0$. The original problem has $a=\sqrt{143}/2$.

Let's write $a=A+\alpha$ where $A=\lfloor a\rfloor$ and $0\le\alpha<1$. Since $kA$ is always an integer, this makes
$$
S = \sum_{k=1}^\infty (kA+\lfloor k\alpha\rfloor)\cdot 2^{-k}
= 2A + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \lfloor k\alpha\rfloor\cdot 2^{-k}
$$
as $\sum_{k=1}^\infty k\cdot 2^{-k}=2$. So, the $A$ term makes no difference.

If $a$ is an integer, $S=2A=2a$ is also an integer. Otherwise, $\alpha>0$, which we will assume from now on.

Now, assuming $0<\alpha<1$, we can rewrite
$$
S-2A = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^{\lfloor k\alpha\rfloor} 2^{-k}
= \sum_{\substack{n,k\ge 1 \\ n\le k\alpha}} 2^{-k}
= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=\lceil n/\alpha\rceil}^\infty 2^{-k}
= \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{1-\lceil n/\alpha\rceil}.
$$
So, we have binary decimal $1$ at locations $\lceil n/\alpha\rceil-1$ for $n=1,2,\ldots$. The average distance between $1$s is $1/\alpha$, which makes their density $\alpha$. Correspondingly, the density of $0$s in the binary expansion is $1-\alpha$.

We could have done a similar derivation using $a=A-\alpha$ where $A=\lceil a\rceil$, in which case we would have ended up subtracting negative powers of $2$ instead of adding them. To see that this results in $0$s at in the binary expansion, think of the initial integer written out as $?.11111\ldots$ from which different negative powers of $2$ are subtracted.

The original problem had $a=\sqrt{143}/2$ which makes $\alpha=a-5=0.979130\ldots$, so the sum $S$ will have $97.9130\ldots\%$ of $1$s in the binary expansion.